# job information not found in JobContext

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I am running a Java program on a remote computer and trying to read the split data using RecordReader object but instead getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: job information not found in JobContext. HCatInputFormat.setInput() not called?
```

I already have called the following:

```
 _hcatInputFmt = HCatInputFormat.setInput(_myJob, db,tbl);
```

and then creating the RecordReader object as:

```
 _hcatInputFmt.createRecordReader(hSplit, taskContext)
```

On debugging it fails while searching for the value of the key: HCAT_KEY_JOB_INFO in job configuration object, while trying to create a RecordReader object.

How do I set this value? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use `getConfiguration()` method to get the configuration from the job object. The configuration object used in creating the job object won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you shuold use:

```
    HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, dbName, inputTableName);
    HCatSchema inputschema = HCatBaseInputFormat.getTableSchema(job.getConfiguration());
```

not

```
    HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, dbName, inputTableName);
    HCatSchema inputschema = HCatBaseInputFormat.getTableSchema(getConf());
```

Because, when you use `Job.getInstance(conf)`, it will copy the conf, you can't use the original conf. Here is the code:

```
 /** 
 * A new configuration with the same settings cloned from another.
 * 
 * @param other the configuration from which to clone settings.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Configuration(Configuration other) {
  this.resources = (ArrayList<Resource>) other.resources.clone();
  synchronized(other) {
 if (other.properties != null) {
   this.properties = (Properties)other.properties.clone();
 }

 if (other.overlay!=null) {
   this.overlay = (Properties)other.overlay.clone();
 }

 this.updatingResource = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String[]>(
     other.updatingResource);
 this.finalParameters = Collections.newSetFromMap(
     new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());
 this.finalParameters.addAll(other.finalParameters);
}

 synchronized(Configuration.class) {
  REGISTRY.put(this, null);
}
this.classLoader = other.classLoader;
this.loadDefaults = other.loadDefaults;
setQuietMode(other.getQuietMode());
}
```